# SQL query that will give me the RecordedValue range each device recorded for each date

Tags: sql

I have a table with this schema:

DeviceID int
FloorID int
RoomID int
DateRecorded datetime
RecordedValue decimal

A sample of the table's data looks like:

```
DeviceID   FloorID   RoomID   DateRecorded RecordedValue
0001       Floor 1   Room 1   1/1/2000     0 
0001       Floor 1   Room 1   1/2/2000     10.5000
0001       Floor 1   Room 1   1/3/2000     18.7500  
0002       Floor 1   Room 2   1/1/2000     10.0000 
0002       Floor 1   Room 2   1/2/2000     10.0000
0002       Floor 1   Room 2   1/3/2000     22.5000
```

I need to build a query that will give me the RecordedValue range each device recorded for each date.

Something like:

```
DeviceID   FloorID   RoomID   DateRecorded  StartValue  EndValue
0001       Floor 1   Room 1   1/1/2000      NULL        0 
0001       Floor 1   Room 1   1/2/2000      0.0001      10.5000 
0001       Floor 1   Room 1   1/3/2000      10.5001     18.7500  
0002       Floor 1   Room 2   1/1/2000      NULL        10.0000 
0002       Floor 1   Room 2   1/2/2000      10.0000     10.0000 
0002       Floor 1   Room 2   1/3/2000      10.0001     22.5000
```

So basically, it has to take the MIN from the previous day's recording if exists or NULL and the MAX from the next day if exists or NULL.

**Each device records the accumulated value each day.**

**Note the issue when the device records the same value for a few days...
Also don't assume that we get a reading every day. We may have gaps in the days recorded.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear.   You appear to be computing the start and end values from the previous day's values according to some formula, but you don't state what the formula is.  for instance, it's not clear to me why Dev 2 on 1/2/2000 has an end value of 22.4999 when the recorded value is 10.000.

Also, you don't state whether each device is limited to a single record per day.

Assuming the following:

1. Each device has only one reading per day.
2. There is a reading every single date.
3. The StartValue for day X is .0001 more than the EndValue for day X-1.

then you can use something like the following query:

```
SELECT D1.DeviceID, D1.FloorID, D1.RoomID, 
       D1.DateRecorded, D2.RecordedValue + .0001 AS StartValue,
       D1.RecordedValue AS EndValue
  FROM YourTable D1 INNER JOIN YourTable D2
  ON D1.DeviceID = D2.DeviceID AND D1.FloorID = D2.FloorID AND 
     D1.RoomID = D2.RoomID AND D1.DateRecorded = D2.DateRecorded+1
```

This will problems with the first or last day in the data set.  You can solve that problem by switching to a LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN, depending on whether you want the first or last date to appear.

Also note that you should factor out FloorID and RoomID from your recorded values table since they appear to depend on DeviceID.  This will normalize your database, reduce storage, and simply the JOIN conditions in the query.

**Edit in response to comments, below:**

If assumption #2 (there's a record for every day) is not valid, then you can use something like this revised version (also changed not to use the .0001 to generate a false start value):

```
SELECT D1.DeviceID, D1.FloorID, D1.RoomID, 
       D1.DateRecorded, D2.RecordedValue AS StartValue,
       D1.RecordedValue AS EndValue
  FROM YourTable D1 INNER JOIN YourTable D2
  ON D1.DeviceID = D2.DeviceID AND D1.FloorID = D2.FloorID AND 
     D1.RoomID = D2.RoomID AND D2.DateRecorded = 
       (SELECT MAX(DateRecorded) FROM YourTable 
          WHERE DeviceID = D1.DeviceID AND FloorID = D1.FloorID AND 
               RoomID = D1.RoomID AND DateRecorded < D1.DateRecorded)
```

And I'll just rewrite this to show you how much smaller it is if you factor out the non-normalized columns:

```
SELECT D1.DeviceID, D1.FloorID, D1.RoomID, 
       D1.DateRecorded, D2.RecordedValue AS StartValue,
       D1.RecordedValue AS EndValue
  FROM YourTable D1 INNER JOIN YourTable D2
  ON D1.DeviceID = D2.DeviceID AND D2.DateRecorded = 
       (SELECT MAX(DateRecorded) FROM YourTable 
          WHERE DeviceID = D1.DeviceID AND DateRecorded < D1.DateRecorded)
```

Comment: Larry,Each device records the accumulated value each day.

Comment: You can't just add .0001 to the previous day's value... Some days the device make record the same value like the day before because of no consumption.

Comment: So why do you add .0001 for the days when there is consumption?  Shouldn't the start value be exactly the end value for the previous day, not + .0001?  Just remove "+ .0001" from the query I wrote, and you'll get what I _think_ you're looking for -- true "start" and "end" values for each day.

Comment: Larry, your query will work but you assume that we get a reading every day. I forgot to mention we may have gaps in the days recorded.

Comment: Yes, as I stated, I made that assumption.  And your revised question also states "Each device records the accumulated value _each_ day".  However, I'll add another query to the answer to handle the skipped days.

Comment: Larry,I need the non-normalized columns because this query will server as a view to get queries against a specific floor or room.
Devices can span to multiple floors/rooms.

Comment: Ah, if floor and room ID are not dependent on device ID, you cannot simply remove them.  However, you should probably still create a separate table with columns ReaderID, DeviceID, FloorID, and RoomID where ReaderID represents a single D/F/R combination.  You can join this table back into the view definition so that searches can be executed the way you want while still eliminating the normalization problem.

Comment: Larry, I added this to your query and is working fine now:     case 
    when D1.RecorderdValue > D2.RecorderdValue
    then D2.RecorderdValue + 0.0001 
    else D1.RecorderdValue  end as StartValue,
    D1.RecorderdValue as EndValue

Comment: Thanks a million Larry, it was easier than I thought, but you guided me to the right path...

Comment: Always a pleasure to be able to help someone out.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DeviceID, DateRecorded, MIN(RecordedValue), MAX(RecordedValue)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY DeviceID, DateRecorded
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: That doesn't give him the sample output he's expecting though. Device 0001 on Floor 1 in Room 1 would return StartValue 10.5 and EndValue 10.5 on 1/2/2000...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to say when you point out the repeated value for several days. Is that incorrect?

```
select DeviceID, min(RecordedValue), max(RecordedValue)
 from yourtable 
group by DeviceID, DateRecorded
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
SELECT   DeviceID, FloorID, RoomdID, DateRecorded
         , COALESCE((SELECT MAX(RecordedValue) 
         FROM RecordedValues a 
         WHERE a.DeviceID = b.DeviceID AND a.DateRecorded < b.DateRecorded), 0) AS StartValue
         , (SELECT MAX(RecordedValue) 
         FROM RecordedValues a 
         WHERE a.DeviceID = b.DeviceID AND a.DateRecorded < b.DateRecorded) AS StartValueWithNulls
         , Recordedvalue AS EndValue
FROM RecordedValues b
```

I wasn't sure if you actually wanted NULLs to be returned so I included a column for dealing with StartValue either way.

Comment: Sorax, that will work too if you add the CASE I added in Larry's query to add 0.0001. Well done..

Comment: Actually this is query is more accurate because it gives me zero (or null) in the start value. You got the answer Sorax.